# How to retrieve rows of a money column in sql with more than 2 digits of precision to the right of the decimal?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am having difficulty figuring out how to select a set of rows from my table where the precision of the value of the row is greater than two digits to the right of the decimal point.  I have no need for any of the values that are 2 digit precision i only want the ones with greater than 2 digit precision.  The end result is that the values with greater than 2 digit precision need to be rounded to constrain the values to only 2 digit precision.  The code that inserts the data has been corrected to only insert values with 2 digit precision but i need to fix the ones that aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there, is your goal to find these records, and then update them? below is what I'm imaging you would need to do :

```
DECLARE @smallmoney as money 

set @smallmoney = 1.0097

SELECT @smallmoney as actualValue, ROUND(@smallmoney,2)
WHERE @smallmoney <> ROUND(@smallmoney,2)
```

As you can see, if the amount of money is already within two decimal points, the where condition will filter that record out.

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I hunted around for an answer to the same problem where some script I had written had created a money column to greater than 2 decimal places - like you I needed to go and find the records that were greater than 2 DP - couldn't find the answer on SO, found the below answer elsewhere though.

```
select ID, MoneyColumn from OurTable
WHERE FLOOR(MoneyColumn*100)!=MoneyColumn*100
```